# powershell break up DN into seperate OU strings

Tags: powershell, csv

We have a report (CSV) which lists computers.  I want to take that report and find the OU information for each computer then seperate out the OU components for better sorting.  I do a foreach loop reading from the CSV file. Then do a get-adcomputer to obtain the DN.
From there I create an array and split the DN into its parts.

```
If(($lineItem.ObjectType -eq "WorkStation") -or ($lineItem.ObjectType -eq "Server"))
     {
     $dn = get-adcomputer -server "washdc.xyz.com" -filter 'name -eq $computer' | Select -expand DistinguishedName
     $ou = $dn.Substring($Computer.Length + 7)
     $domain = "Washdc"
     $ou = $ou -replace ",DC=washdc,dc=xyz,dc=com",""
     $ou = $ou -replace "ou=",""
     $Ouarray = $ou.split(",")
         For ($i=0; $i-le $ouarray.length-1;$i++) not sure what to do here?
```

I want to create a variable for each OU (like $OU1, $OU2, etc...) as $i increases.  The ultimate goal is to reverse the OU listing so it can be output in a top down format...showing OU7,OU6,Ou5, all the way down to 0.  Am I making this too complicated?

Comment: Any reason not to use the CanonicalName property?

Comment: Cn just gives me the computername? or is this some PS command?

Comment: Cn is CommonName.  CanonicalName is a different property.  get-adcomputer -server "washdc.xyz.com" -filter 'name -eq $computer' -property CanonicalName | Select -expand CanonicalName

Comment: Son of a @#$%!  I never saw that one before...doesnt even show up in ADSI edit. Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't show up in ADSI because it's a calculated property.

Comment: @mjolinor Why not add it as an answer? I'll vote up, sure..

Answer (score 2):

AD provides a calculated property called CanonicalName that should give you the object's AD location in the order you want:

```
get-adcomputer -server "washdc.xyz.com" -filter 'name -eq $computer' -property CanonicalName | Select -expand CanonicalName
```

Note that this is a calculated property, so it does not show up in ADSIEdit as an attribute of the object.